# Django and materialized views

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I have connected my Postgres ddbb with django. With inspectdb I have brought all my tables to models.py.
However, I can't find any command for **bringing my materialized views to models.py**

I have tryed:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=name_ddbb --include-views
```

But it only gives me the views, not the materialized views.

**How can I add automatically the materialized views to django?**

Thanks!

Comment: what Django version do you use

Comment: Version django 3.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name of the PostgreSQL materialized view as a parameter to the `inspectdb` call. In my case, it helped.

Note that you'll probably have to make small changes manually in the resulting model code. In particular, indicate that the `id` field is the primary key.

You can see the detailed example of the PostgreSQL materialized view in Django [in this repository](https://github.com/s-kust/django-postgresql-view).

Working code pieces illustrating the following:

1. PostgreSQL materialized view in Django.
2. `EagerLoadingMixin` in Django REST framework serializer classes to
   solve the N+1 queries problem.
3. Usage of the most generic `viewsets.ModelViewSet` to build views in
   Django REST framework fast and easy.
4. Advanced PostgreSQL SQL Query with several Common Table Expressions
   and JSON functions.
5. Django `post_save` and `m2m_changed` signals.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate your materialized views to the Django with this library [django-materialized-view](https://github.com/muehlemann-popp/django-materialized-view)

Everything what you need:

1. Get view_definitions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.views
WHERE table_schema = 'information_schema'
AND table_name = 'views';
```

2. use [django-materialized-view](https://github.com/muehlemann-popp/django-materialized-view) according to the description
3. Enjoy with materialized views in your project.